# Create PSCredential without a password

Tags: .net, powershell, powershell-2.0, system.management

How to create a instance of PSCredential that has no password? (Without manually filling out a `Get-Credential` dialog with no password, this is for unattended running.)

Things I tried:

1. `$mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("username", $null)`
   Error: Cannot process argument because the value of argument "password" is null
2. `$mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("username", (ConvertTo-SecureString $null -AsPlainText -Force))`
   Error: ConvertTo-SecureString : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'String' because it is null.
3. `$mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("username", (ConvertTo-SecureString "" -AsPlainText -Force))`
   Error: ConvertTo-SecureString : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'String' because it is an empty string.

Comment: pscredential requires a password.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Solution:

```
$mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential 
              ("username", (new-object System.Security.SecureString))
```

Comment: hi @EugeneO hope u can assist me with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9290830/powershell-secure-string-conversion tks

Comment: PowerShell is too convoluted for there to be such a thing as a dumb question.

Comment: Annoying seems you must handle the two cases with and empty and a filled password.  ConvertTo-SecureString is hilariously useless: "Cannot bind argument to parameter 'String' because it is an empty string." well gee.

Comment: this is a bad idea

Answer (score -2):

Use the Get-Credential cmdlet, when the credential dialog appears, don't type a password

```
$cred = Get-Credential pebrian27
$cred.GetNetworkCredential() | select UserName,Password

UserName   Password
--------   --------
pebrian27
```

Comment: -1 - A dialog coming up and you not entering something is not the context of what the OP was asking. And the OP had given a proper answer as well, no need for this answer.

Comment: There might be more than one solution and I don't see where the OP specifically asked not to use a cmdlet.

Comment: I am not talking about a cmdlet. Of course you can use a cmdlet ( what is powershell without cmdlets!!) I am talking about a manual intervention, where a dialog box appears, you then don't enter password and return back. That is not a practical solution. Everytime a script runs, you expect to get that dialog and return back?

Comment: I suggest you read the question again. There's nothing in it with regard to manual intervention.

Comment: @Shay Levy - I'm avoid the credential prompt. But yes, I should have explicitly specified that