# Powershell secure string conversion

Tags: sql-server, powershell, ssms

Hi I am trying to do this

```
Import-Csv C:\sl.csv |$pass = convertto-securestring "abc123"-asplaintext -force | ForEach-Object {New-Item $(Encode-Sqlname $_.Name) -ItemType Registration -Value ("server=$($_.Name);integrated security=true") -Credential (New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential("sa", $pass)) }
```

but getting error like this

```
Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline.
At line:1 char:29
+ Import-Csv C:\sl.csv |$pass  <<<< = convertto-securestring "abc123"-asplaintext -fo
rce | ForEach-Object {New-Item $(Encode-Sqlname $_.Name) -ItemType Registration -Value ("server=$($_.Name);integrated security=true") -Credential (New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential("sa", $pass)) }
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpressionsMustBeFirstInPipeline
```

I basically want to be able to add the username and password (use sql authentication) and trying to convert my password to securestring and not doing a good job from the look of this. Pls assist tks
I went to this link and the code there was helpful but the problem was when I right click on my registered servers and saw the properties I see that it is in windows authentication mode and not in sql authentication mode

Answer (score 0):

Try to assign value at $pass before the piping:

```
$pass = convertto-securestring "abc123"-asplaintext -force 
Import-Csv C:\sl.csv | ForEach-Object {New-Item $(Encode-Sqlname $_.Name) -ItemType Registration -Value ("server=$($_.Name);integrated security=true") -Credential (New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential("sa", $pass)) }
```

Comment: But strangely when i try to connect the default connection is set to windows authentication and not to SQL authentication, so i changed the integrated security to false and now i am able to see SQL authentication selected but the username and password are blank so where is my sa and password gone too? something wrong i am doing?