# How to create a Windows Service in Powershell for "Network Service" account?

Tags: powershell, windows-7, windows-services

I want to create a Windows Service using Powershell. Creating it for a given user is piece of cake. I used this function adapted from [here](https://github.com/yaplex/CodeSamples/blob/master/PowerShell/Install-Windows-Service.ps1).

```
function ReinstallService1 ($serviceName, $binaryPath, $login, $pass)
{  
    Write-Host "installing service"
    # creating credentials which can be used to run my windows service
    $secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString $pass -AsPlainText -Force
    $mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($login, $secpasswd)

    # creating widnows service using all provided parameters
    New-Service -name $serviceName -binaryPathName $binaryPath -displayName $serviceName -startupType Automatic -credential $mycreds
    Write-Host "installation completed"
}
```

My question is: **How can I create for "Network Service" account?**

If I modify **New-Service** line and remove credential parameter, the service is created for **"Local System"** account. Nearly miss.

```
New-Service -name $serviceName -binaryPathName $binaryPath -displayName $serviceName -startupType Automatic
```

I googled a lot and saw no way of indicating service account. If I try to use Credential parameter for user **"NETWORK SSERVICE"**, I don't know what password to put and if I invent one (just in case cmdlet ignores it) it doesn't work. The error is:

> New-Service : Service 'XXXX (XXXX)'
>   cannot be created due to the following error: **The account name is
>   invalid or does not exist, or the password is invalid for the account
>   name specified**

Comment: Could you share your exact New-Service Line? When I use something like this:

New-Service -name $serviceName -binaryPathName $path -displayName $serviceName -startupType Automatic -Credential "NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE"

I get a password prompt.

Comment: The problem is that you are passing only username in -Credential.

My line is as yours but I pass -Credential $MyCreds

$MyCreds value is: $MyCreds= $mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($login, $secpasswd)

$login value is "NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE" $secpassword can be anything.

Comment: @Aniket, I have added an answer with the final version of the script so you can see it better than in my comment...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The correct name of the account is `NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE`.

Comment: No that is not the correct name, the correct name is depending on the language of the system you are executing on and can be found out like so:

$SID = [System.Security.Principal.WellKnownSidType]::NetworkServiceSid
$Account = new-object system.security.principal.securityidentifier($SID, $null)
$NetworkServiceName = $Account.Translate([system.security.principal.ntaccount]).value

Answer (score 17):

This is the final version of Reinstall Service for everyone's benefit, specially for Aniket.

```
function ReinstallService ($serviceName, $binaryPath, $description, $login, $password, $startUpType)
{
        Write-Host "Trying to create service: $serviceName"

        #Check Parameters
        if ((Test-Path $binaryPath)-eq $false)
        {
            Write-Host "BinaryPath to service not found: $binaryPath"
            Write-Host "Service was NOT installed."
            return
        }

        if (("Automatic", "Manual", "Disabled") -notcontains $startUpType)
        {
            Write-Host "Value for startUpType parameter should be (Automatic or Manual or Disabled) and it was $startUpType"
            Write-Host "Service was NOT installed."
            return
        }

        # Verify if the service already exists, and if yes remove it first
        if (Get-Service $serviceName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
        {
            # using WMI to remove Windows service because PowerShell does not have CmdLet for this
            $serviceToRemove = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -Filter "name='$serviceName'"

            $serviceToRemove.delete()
            Write-Host "Service removed: $serviceName"
        }

        # if password is empty, create a dummy one to allow have credentias for system accounts: 
        #NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE
        #NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
        if ($password -eq "") 
        {
            #$secpassword = (new-object System.Security.SecureString)
            # Bug detected by @GaTechThomas
            $secpasswd = (new-object System.Security.SecureString)
        }
        else
        {
            $secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
        }
        $mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($login, $secpasswd)

        # Creating Windows Service using all provided parameters
        Write-Host "Installing service: $serviceName"
        New-Service -name $serviceName -binaryPathName $binaryPath -Description $description -displayName $serviceName -startupType $startUpType -credential $mycreds

        Write-Host "Installation completed: $serviceName"

        # Trying to start new service
        Write-Host "Trying to start new service: $serviceName"
        $serviceToStart = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -Filter "name='$serviceName'"
        $serviceToStart.startservice()
        Write-Host "Service started: $serviceName"

        #SmokeTest
        Write-Host "Waiting 5 seconds to give time service to start..."
        Start-Sleep -s 5
        $SmokeTestService = Get-Service -Name $serviceName
        if ($SmokeTestService.Status -ne "Running")
        {
            Write-Host "Smoke test: FAILED. (SERVICE FAILED TO START)"
            Throw "Smoke test: FAILED. (SERVICE FAILED TO START)"
        }
        else
        {
            Write-Host "Smoke test: OK."
        }

}
```

Comment: This may have the strange side effect that if a user's password is `dummy` and the caller doesn't give a password, it will just work.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6839924/1394393) offers a way to create an empty `SecureString`.

Comment: Bug in this code: $secpassword should be $secpasswd

Answer (score 8):

You could get a cred of network service straightforward like this:

```
$login = "NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE"
#### #just set a dummy psw since it's just used to get credentials

$psw = "dummy"

$scuritypsw = ConvertTo-SecureString $psw -AsPlainText -Force

$mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($login, $scuritypsw)
#### #then you can use the cred to new a windows service

$serviceName = "Test"
$binaryPath = "C:\Test\Test.exe"

New-Service -name $serviceName -binaryPathName $binaryPath -displayName $serviceName -startupType Automatic -credential $mycreds
```

Answer (score 0):

`Get-WmiObject` is deprecated now. However, PowerShell now has built in cmdlets to work with services. Here is the updated version of `ReinstallService` from Oscar Foley's answer tweaked accordingly along with convenient default values and wrappers to start and stop a service:

```
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35064964/powershell-script-to-check-if-service-is-started-if-not-then-start-it
function TryStopService([string] $serviceName)
{
    Write-Host "Attempting to stop service: $serviceName..."
    $service = Get-Service -Name $serviceName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

    if($service)
    {
        if ($service.Status -ne 'Running')
        {
            Write-Host "    Service: $serviceName is not running."
        }
        else
        {
            Stop-Service -name $serviceName
            Write-Host "    Stopped service: $serviceName."
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host "    Service: $serviceName is not found."
    }
}

function UninstallService([string] $serviceName)
{
    Write-Host "Attempting to uninstall service: $serviceName..."
    if (Get-Service $serviceName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
    {
        Remove-Service -Name $serviceName
        Write-Host "    Uninstalled service: $serviceName."
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host "    Service: $serviceName is not found."
    }
}

function StartSertice([string] $serviceName)
{
    Write-Host "Attempting to start service: $serviceName..."
    $service = Get-Service -Name $serviceName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

    if($service)
    {
        if ($service.Status -eq 'Running')
        {
            Write-Host "    Service: $serviceName is already running."
            return
        }
    }

    # Trying to start new service.
    Write-Host "    Trying to start new service: $serviceName."
    Start-Service -Name $serviceName

    #Check that service has started.
    Write-Host "    Waiting 5 seconds to give service time to start..."
    Start-Sleep -s 5
    $testService = Get-Service -Name $serviceName

    if ($testService.Status -ne "Running")
    {
        [string] $errMessage = "    Failed to start service: $serviceName"
        Write-Host $errMessage
        Throw $errMessage
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host "    Started service: $serviceName."
    }
}

function ReinstallService ([string] $serviceName, [string] $binaryPath, [string] $description = "", [string] $login = "NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE", [string] $password = "", [string] $startUpType = "Automatic")
{
    Write-Host "Attempting to reinstall service: $serviceName..."

    #Check Parameters
    if ((Test-Path $binaryPath)-eq $false)
    {
        Write-Host "    BinaryPath to service was not found: $binaryPath."
        Write-Host "    Service was NOT installed."
        return
    }

    if (("Automatic", "Manual", "Disabled") -notcontains $startUpType)
    {
        Write-Host "    Value for startUpType parameter should be (Automatic or Manual or Disabled) and it was $startUpType"
        Write-Host "    Service was NOT installed."
        return
    }

    TryStopService -serviceName $serviceName
    UninstallService -serviceName $serviceName

    # if password is empty, create a dummy one to allow having credentias for system accounts:
    #     NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE
    #     NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
    if ($password -eq "")
    {
        $secpassword = (new-object System.Security.SecureString)
    }
    else
    {
        $secpassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
    }

    $mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($login, $secpassword)

    # Creating Windows Service using all provided parameters.
    Write-Host "Installing service: $serviceName with user name: '$login'..."
    New-Service -name $serviceName -binaryPathName $binaryPath -Description $description -displayName $serviceName -startupType $startUpType -credential $mycreds
    Write-Host "    Installed service: $serviceName."

    # Trying to start new service.
    StartSertice -serviceName $serviceName
}
```