# Powershell script to check if service is started, if not then start it

Tags: powershell

I have built a small powershell script to check if a service is started.  If it is not started, try to start it then wait one minute and check again.  Keep repeating this process until the service start successfully.  I have found the loop does not behave the way I expected in that I seem to have to re-assign the service variable within the loop in order to get the updated status.  Here is my code:

```
$ServiceName = 'Serenade'
$arrService = Get-Service -Name $ServiceName

if ($arrService.Status -ne 'Running'){
$ServiceStarted = $false}
Else{$ServiceStarted = $true}

while ($ServiceStarted -ne $true){
Start-Service $ServiceName
write-host $arrService.status
write-host 'Service started'
Start-Sleep -seconds 60
$arrService = Get-Service -Name $ServiceName #Why is this line needed?
if ($arrService.Status -eq 'Running'){
$ServiceStarted = $true}
}
```

If I run the code without the third last line (the one with the comment), I get the following output.  I can check in the Windows service manager and the service was clearly started after the first loop.  Why is that third last line required?

[image]

Given this behavior, is there a better way to write this code?

Thank you

Comment: Its because the variable status of the service is stored, for you to have it work it needs to get the status of the service again.

Comment: Aren't I checking the status on the second last line?  The one with `if($arrService.Status...`?

Comment: You are but you are checking it from a variable that is already set, that variable is not called again without that line to update that variable.

Comment: Sorry to be thick, but I'm a ps newbie.  I'm intending to look up the service's status, and if it is 'Running', change the $ServiceStarted variable to true.  Once that is done, the initial loop condition will be re-evaluated and that $ServiceStarted variable will be checked again, so wouldn't it find the updated value of true?

Comment: What is it your trying to accomplish? check that the service is running and then start if its not running. Stop re-evaluating until it's started?

Comment: Yes, we have a service that is currently started by a batch file around midnight each night, but sometimes it fails to start and we don't notice until we get in the next morning and we have to manually start it.  I want the ps script to keep trying to start it until it actually starts.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101910/discussion-between-dave-gugg-and-nick-eagle).

Answer (score 69, accepted):

I think you may have over-complicated your code: If you are just checking to see if a service is running and, if not, run it and then stop re-evaluating, the following should suffice:

[Good point on the refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35065807/45375).

```
$ServiceName = 'Serenade'
$arrService = Get-Service -Name $ServiceName

while ($arrService.Status -ne 'Running')
{

    Start-Service $ServiceName
    write-host $arrService.status
    write-host 'Service starting'
    Start-Sleep -seconds 60
    $arrService.Refresh()
    if ($arrService.Status -eq 'Running')
    {
        Write-Host 'Service is now Running'
    }

}
```

Comment: in my PC "service" class members have this values
State     : Running
Status   : OK

Comment: Made a gist with a slightly altered version, making it easier to setup multiple services that should be started: https://gist.github.com/JohnyWS/6d0df355bfa63b05e5405c1c3939c69b

Comment: are we 100% sure this works - how does `arrService` get updated ?  The comment below alludes to the idea that its a static property as well.

Comment: @jayunit100 that's what the `.Refresh()` is for

Answer (score 9):

A potentially simpler solution:

```
get-service "servicename*" | Where {$_.Status -neq 'Running'} | start-service
```

Comment: The question was if service is not running. Checking for "Stopped" instead of "Running" is not correct. There are more statuses than these two.

Answer (score 6):

Given `$arrService = Get-Service -Name $ServiceName`, `$arrService.Status` is a *static* property, corresponding to the value at the time of the call. Use `$arrService.Refresh()` when needed to renew the properties to current values.

> [MSDN ~ ServiceController.Refresh()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.refresh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
>
> Refreshes property values by resetting the properties to their current values.

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I didn't understand.

Answer (score 2):

Combining Alaa Akoum and Nick Eagle's solutions allowed me to loop through a series of windows services and stop them if they're running.

```
# stop the following Windows services in the specified order:
[Array] $Services = 'Service1','Service2','Service3','Service4','Service5';

# loop through each service, if its running, stop it
foreach($ServiceName in $Services)
{
    $arrService = Get-Service -Name $ServiceName
    write-host $ServiceName
    while ($arrService.Status -eq 'Running')
    {
        Stop-Service $ServiceName
        write-host $arrService.status
        write-host 'Service stopping'
        Start-Sleep -seconds 60
        $arrService.Refresh()
        if ($arrService.Status -eq 'Stopped')
            {
              Write-Host 'Service is now Stopped'
            }
     }
 }
```

The same can be done to start a series of service if they are not running:

```
# start the following Windows services in the specified order:
[Array] $Services = 'Service1','Service2','Service3','Service4','Service5';

# loop through each service, if its not running, start it
foreach($ServiceName in $Services)
{
    $arrService = Get-Service -Name $ServiceName
    write-host $ServiceName
    while ($arrService.Status -ne 'Running')
    {
        Start-Service $ServiceName
        write-host $arrService.status
        write-host 'Service starting'
        Start-Sleep -seconds 60
        $arrService.Refresh()
        if ($arrService.Status -eq 'Running')
        {
          Write-Host 'Service is now Running'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The below is a compact script that will check if "running" and attempt start service until the service returns as running.

```
$Service = 'ServiceName'
If ((Get-Service $Service).Status -ne 'Running') {
   do {
       Start-Service $Service -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
       Start-Sleep 10
   } until ((Get-Service $Service).Status -eq 'Running')
} Return "$($Service) has STARTED"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ServiceName = 'Serenade'
$arrService = Get-Service -Name $ServiceName

while ($arrService.Status -ne 'Running')
{

    Start-Service $ServiceName
    write-host $arrService.status
    write-host 'Service starting'
    Start-Sleep -seconds 60
    $arrService.Refresh()
    if ($arrService.Status -eq 'Running')
    {
        Write-Host 'Service is now Running'
    }

}
```

Can we use the same script for multiple services and send a single email if services are down.

Answer (score 1):

```
[Array] $servers = "Server1","server2";
$service='YOUR SERVICE'

foreach($server in $servers)

{
    $srvc = Get-WmiObject -query "SELECT * FROM win32_service  WHERE   name LIKE '$service' " -computername $server  ;
    $res=Write-Output $srvc | Format-Table -AutoSize $server, $fmtMode, $fmtState, $fmtStatus ;  
   $srvc.startservice() 
   $res
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: how could one allow multiple services to be checked?

Comment: nest a second for loop and have a second array of services

Answer (score 1):

Trying to do things as smooth as possible - I here suggest modifying GuyWhoLikesPowershell's suggestion slightly.

I replaced the if and until with one while - and I check for "Stopped", since I don't want to start if status is "starting" or " Stopping".

```
$Service = 'ServiceName'
while ((Get-Service $Service).Status -eq 'Stopped') 
{
    Start-Service $Service -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    Start-Sleep 10
} 
Return "$($Service) has STARTED"
```

Answer (score 1):

### Context

We have a product that has many variations and we work on them at once. Each variations has its own service. When multiple people work on the same version and one person manages to crash the service then someone needs to connect on the machine remotely and fix it.

### Solution

So I made something that could manage multiple instances. Luckily all of them have the same prefix and `Get-Service` can take a *"wildcard"*.

```
$ServiceName = 'ASService_*'; # Your wildcard goes here.

while ($true)
{
    Get-Service $ServiceName | Where {$_.Status -eq 'Stopped'} | Foreach-Object {
        Start-Service $_;
        # Logging it so that you know it was you.
        Get-Date;
        Write-Output "``$($_.Name)`` has stopped running.";
    }
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1;
}
```

This can be further simplified if you don't care about logs.

```
$ServiceName = 'ASService_*'; # Your wildcard goes here.

while ($true)
{
    Get-Service $ServiceName | Where {$_.Status -eq 'Stopped'} | Foreach-Object { Start-Service $_ };
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the spirit of [Enterprise FizzBuzz](https://github.com/EnterpriseQualityCoding/FizzBuzzEnterpriseEdition), I wrote a version with extensive logging and handling for errors and Pending service states. It's likely over-engineered for most use cases. Please note this version is specifically intended be invoked by a Windows Scheduled Task on an interval. It runs for a specified number of tries on each run before stopping.

```
<#
.SYNOPSIS
This script attempts to Start the specified Windows service if the service is stopped and logs its attempts to a file.
It's intended to be deployed as a Windows Scheduled Task that runs every few minutes. 
Please ensure the Scheduled Task interval is longer than (($secondsBeforeRetry + 10s) * $maxTries) to avoid concurrent running script instances.

The script first checks the existence of the log file and if not found creates a new one. 
It then checks the status of the specified Windows service. 
If it's not Stopped (implicitly Running), no actions occur and the script completes without logging anything.
If it's Stopped, the script attempts to Start it and logs success or failure. 
If the service is still Stopped, the script will try to Start it again up to $maxTries times.
If the service is in a Starting (StartPending) or Stopping (StopPending) state, the script will recheck its status for 
up to three $secondsBeforeRetry intervals to see if it changes. 
If the service is still Pending after three checks, the process is likely hung and the script will attempt to force taskkill it.

References: 
List of ServiceControllerStatus states: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.servicecontrollerstatus?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0
The script does not handle the Paused, PausedPending, or ContinuePending service states.
#>


param (
    # Specifies the service name
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [string]$serviceName,
    
    # Specifies the directory for the log file
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
    [string]$logPath = 'C:\Scripts\Logs',
    
    # Specifies the max number of service Start attempts per run
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
    [int]$maxTries = 3,
    
    # Specifies the number of seconds to wait before trying again after a failed start attempt or before rechecking a Pending status
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
    [int]$secondsBeforeRetry = 30

)

$service = Get-Service $serviceName
$logName = $serviceName + 'AutoRestartLog.txt'
$logFullPath = Join-Path -Path $logPath -ChildPath $logName

if(!(Test-Path -Path $logFullPath)) {
    $timestamp = (Get-Date -Format yyyy-MM-dd--HH-mm-ss)
    New-Item -Path $logPath -Name $logName -ItemType "file" -Value "## Log file for $serviceName auto-start script ##`n## Created [$timestamp] ##`n" -Force
    Start-Sleep -s 1
}

if ($service.Status -eq 'Stopped') {
    $tries = 0
    
    while (($tries -lt $maxTries) -and ($service.Status -ne 'Running')) {
        if ($tries -eq 0) {
            $timestamp = (Get-Date -Format yyyy-MM-dd--HH-mm-ss)
            $logSvcStoppedMsg = "[$timestamp] $serviceName service status is $($service.Status), attempting to Start. Will try up to $maxTries times."
            Add-Content -Path $logFullPath -Value $logSvcStoppedMsg
        }
        
        try {
            Start-Service $ServiceName -ErrorAction Stop # Throws exception if command fails, for example if the service is Disabled
            $tries += 1
            Start-Sleep -s 10
            $service.Refresh()
            if ($service.Status -eq 'Running') {
                $timestamp = (Get-Date -Format yyyy-MM-dd--HH-mm-ss)
                $logSvcStartSuccessMsg = "[$timestamp] Attempt #$tries - $serviceName service status is now $($service.Status)"
                Add-Content -Path $logFullPath -Value $logSvcStartSuccessMsg
            }

        }
        catch {
            $errorMsg = $_
            $tries += 1
            Start-Sleep -s 10
            $service.Refresh()
            $timestamp = (Get-Date -Format yyyy-MM-dd--HH-mm-ss)
            $logSvcStartExceptionMsg = "[$timestamp] Attempt #$tries - $serviceName service status is $($service.Status) and failed to start with error:`n    $errorMsg"
            Add-Content -Path $logFullPath -Value $logSvcStartExceptionMsg
            if ($tries -ne $maxTries) {
                Start-Sleep -s $secondsBeforeRetry
            }
        }
        
        $service.Refresh()
        if (($service.Status -eq 'StartPending') -or ($service.Status -eq 'StopPending')) {
            $maxStateChecks = 3
            $stateChecks = 0
            
            while (($stateChecks -lt $maxStateChecks) -and (($service.Status -eq 'StartPending') -or ($service.Status -eq 'StopPending'))) {
                $timestamp = (Get-Date -Format yyyy-MM-dd--HH-mm-ss)
                $logSvcStillPendingMsg = "[$timestamp] Attempt #$tries - $serviceName service status is $($service.Status). This may indicate the service is hung in the Starting or Stopping state. Waiting another $secondsBeforeRetry seconds before checking again."
                Add-Content -Path $logFullPath -Value $logSvcStillPendingMsg
                $stateChecks += 1
                if ($stateChecks -ne $maxStateChecks) {
                    Start-Sleep -s $secondsBeforeRetry
                }
                $service.Refresh()
                if ($service.Status -eq 'Running') {
                    $timestamp = (Get-Date -Format yyyy-MM-dd--HH-mm-ss)
                    $logSvcStartSuccessMsg = "[$timestamp] Attempt #$tries - $serviceName service status is now $($service.Status)"
                    Add-Content -Path $logFullPath -Value $logSvcStartSuccessMsg
                } elseif ($service.Status -eq 'Stopped') {
                    $timestamp = (Get-Date -Format yyyy-MM-dd--HH-mm-ss)
                    $logSvcStoppedAfterPendingMsg = "[$timestamp] Attempt #$tries - $serviceName service status is now $($service.Status). If any Start attempts remain the script will try again on the next loop."
                    Add-Content -Path $logFullPath -Value $logSvcStoppedAfterPendingMsg
                }
            }
            
            $service.Refresh()
            if (($stateChecks -eq $maxStateChecks) -and (($service.Status -eq 'StartPending') -or ($service.Status -eq 'StopPending'))) {
                $timestamp = (Get-Date -Format yyyy-MM-dd--HH-mm-ss)
                $logSvcStuckPendingMsg = "[$timestamp] Attempt #$tries - $serviceName service status appears stuck in a Pending (Starting or Stopping) state. Attempting to force kill process."
                Add-Content -Path $logFullPath -Value $logSvcStuckPendingMsg
                
                $servicePID = Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_Service -Filter "Name LIKE '$serviceName'" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ProcessId
                $resultMsg = taskkill /pid $servicePID /f
                $timestamp = (Get-Date -Format yyyy-MM-dd--HH-mm-ss)
                $logSvcTaskKillMsg = "[$timestamp] Attempt #$tries - taskkill result:`n    $resultMsg"
                Add-Content -Path $logFullPath -Value $logSvcTaskKillMsg
                
                Start-Sleep -s 10
                $service.Refresh()
                $timestamp = (Get-Date -Format yyyy-MM-dd--HH-mm-ss)
                $logSvcStatusMsg = "[$timestamp] Attempt #$tries - $serviceName service status is now $($service.Status)"
                Add-Content -Path $logFullPath -Value $logSvcStatusMsg
            }
        }
        
        if (($tries -eq $maxTries) -and ($service.Status -ne 'Running')) {
            $timestamp = (Get-Date -Format yyyy-MM-dd--HH-mm-ss)
            $logNoMoreAttemptsMsg = "[$timestamp] $serviceName service status is $($service.Status) after $maxTries Start attempts. This run of the script will not continue trying to Start the service."
            Add-Content -Path $logFullPath -Value $logNoMoreAttemptsMsg
        }
    }
    
    # Add line break at end of log file entry
    Add-Content -Path $logFullPath -Value "`n"
}
```

It outputs a log file that looks like this:

```
## Log file for Netman auto-start script ##
## Created [2022-07-11--22-55-38] ##

[2022-07-11--23-25-53] Netman service status is Stopped, attempting to Start. Will try up to 3 times.
[2022-07-11--23-26-03] Attempt #1 - Netman service status is Stopped and failed to start with error:
    Service 'Network Connections (Netman)' cannot be started due to the following error: Cannot start service Netman on computer '.'.
[2022-07-11--23-26-43] Attempt #2 - Netman service status is Stopped and failed to start with error:
    Service 'Network Connections (Netman)' cannot be started due to the following error: Cannot start service Netman on computer '.'.
[2022-07-11--23-27-23] Attempt #3 - Netman service status is Stopped and failed to start with error:
    Service 'Network Connections (Netman)' cannot be started due to the following error: Cannot start service Netman on computer '.'.
[2022-07-11--23-27-53] Netman service status is Stopped after 3 Start attempts. This run of the script will not continue trying to Start the service.

[2022-07-12--01-46-15] Netman service status is Stopped, attempting to Start. Will try up to 3 times.
[2022-07-12--01-46-25] Attempt #1 - Netman service status is now Running
```

Answer (score 0):

Start the service if it is stopped

```
Get-Service "servicename*" | Where {$_.Status -ne 'Stopped'} | Start-Service
```