# How do I start multiple services in a specific order and if there is no service available, it will skip to the next available one?

Tags: powershell

This script will find the services listed in the variables set.  If the service is not running, it will start the service.  It also checks and starts the service in a specific order.  It also reads the servers from a text file.

However, the question here is how do you make it so that if the service is not available, it will skip to the next available service?  Currently, the script just stops when there is no service available.

```
Function startOTCSServices {

$ComputerPath = "C:\PS Scripts\OTCS CSIRT\servernames.otcs.txt"
$OTCSServicePath = "KIC-ED-MC02"
$OTCSServicePath1 = "KIC-ED-MC"
$OTCSServicePath2 = "Ascent Capture Service"
$OTCSServicePath3 = "ACIS Remote Synchronization Agent"

try {
    $ComputerNames = Get-Content -Path $ComputerPath  

    if ($ComputerNames -ne $null) 
    {    

        foreach ($c in $ComputerNames) 
        {
            Write-Host "Server:" $c -ForegroundColor Yellow
            Write-Host "-------------------------------------------"
            Write-Host "Starting Services"
            Write-Host "-------------------------------------------"

            $p = Get-Service -Name $OTCSServicePath -ComputerName $c -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
            $p1 = Get-Service -Name $OTCSServicePath1 -ComputerName $c -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
            $p2 = Get-Service -Name $OTCSServicePath2 -ComputerName $c -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
            $p3 = Get-Service -Name $OTCSServicePath3 -ComputerName $c -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

                while ($p.Status -ne "Running") 
                {              
                    Start-Service $p -Verbose                          
                    Start-Sleep -s 5
                    $p.Refresh() 
                    if ($p.Status -eq "Running") 
                    {
                        Write-Host $p "is now started" -ForegroundColor Green 
                    }
                }
                while ($p1.Status -ne "Running") 
                {   
                    Start-Service $p1 -Verbose                          
                    Start-Sleep -s 5
                    $p1.Refresh() 
                    if ($p1.Status -eq "Running") 
                    {
                        Write-Host $p1 "is now started" -ForegroundColor Green
                    }
                }
                while ($p2.Status -ne "Running") 
                {   
                    Start-Service $p2 -Verbose                          
                    Start-Sleep -s 5
                    $p2.Refresh() 
                    if ($p2.Status -eq "Running") 
                    {
                        Write-Host $p2 "is now started" -ForegroundColor Green
                    }
                }
                while ($p3.Status -ne "Running") 
                {   
                    Start-Service $p3 -Verbose                          
                    Start-Sleep -s 5
                    $p3.Refresh() 
                    if ($p3.Status -eq "Running") 
                    {
                        Write-Host $p3 "is now started" -ForegroundColor Green
                    }
                }
         }             
    } else { Write-Host "No computers found in file" }
     } catch { Write-Host $_ }
```

}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Powershell script to check if service is started, if not then start it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35064964/powershell-script-to-check-if-service-is-started-if-not-then-start-it)

Comment: instead of feeding in all three services to the same command, use a loop over the list. keep checking for "is it running yet?" OR simply use `Start-Sleep` for however long you think is adequate.

Comment: thanks for the replies guys.  I've changed my script a little to try to get the specific order.  However, is there a way to make it so that if the SERVICE does NOT exist, to skip it and move on to start the NEXT service?