# How do I check if a Powershell script is still running before triggering a new instance?

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0, powershell-remoting

Powershell Queue triggers

I have a powershell script which is triggered from task scheduler for different trigeres. I need to check if the previous execution is completed or not, if not completed, the triggered one should wait untill the previous execution is completed.

Comment: Register a service with the script. Then check if the service is running: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35064964/powershell-script-to-check-if-service-is-started-if-not-then-start-it

Comment: The question has nothing to even hint at why `node-red` or `openflow` tags would be relevant, so removed.

Comment: A task has a setting to specify what happens when an instance of a task already runs. Choose "queue a new instance" to get the behaviour you want.

Comment: how to do it, i am completely new to powershell

Comment: You don't need PowerShell for this, just look into the task settings.