# How can I debug an application as a service account (f.e. network service) in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, network-service

Windows has different [built-in standard service accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/510225), f.e. the `NetworkService` account. This [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287099/runas-a-different-user-when-debugging-in-visual-studio) provides different answers on how to debug code as a different user than the current one when debugging in Visual Studio, but these answers show solutions for different local user accounts / admin accounts that request passwords to run code (these built-in accounts have no passwords). Is there a way to run and debug code from Visual Studio as one of these built-in service accounts?

---

My use case: I want to debug a service (and tests) that runs in production as the `NetworkService` account. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17973778) explains how to run an application as a `NetworkService` by using [PsExec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec). Can I somehow start the service or tests with PsExec and then attach Visual Studio to the process and debug it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is actually pretty easy and straight forward:

---

**1. Execute the application with the desired service account to have a running process that the Visual Studio debugger can attach itself to**

This can just be done by registering as a service, and either entering the service account credentials in the `Service` app, by right clicking on the service name -> **Properties** and setting the account in the **Log on** tab, or via PowerShell, like it is [described in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30496601).

Another way is to use [PsExec](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/downloads/psexec) as [described in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6911310/how-do-i-run-as-network-service). After downloading PsExec, run the following command inside a shell to open a cmd as a service account, f.e. for the network service account:

```
psexec -i -u "nt authority\network service" cmd.exe
```

Run `whoami` in the cmd to ensure that it is getting executed as the desired account. Now navigate to the executable that should be debugged, and launch it from this cmd.

---

Note: I added a sleep at the beginning of my app to ensure that it does not execute any code until I connected with a debugger to it (C++ example):

```cpp
while (!IsDebuggerPresent())
{
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));
}
```

---

**2. Attach the Visual Studio debugger to the running process**

Open Visual Studio as Administrator, click on Debug -> Attach to Process to open the `Attach to Process` window. Once the window is open, make sure to click the `Show processes for all users` checkbox when searching for the process, since it is getting executed under a different user account. Then search for the process that has been started in the previous step and click on `Attach`. It should now be possible to debug the app.

[image]